# "to walk something" meaning "to carry something"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

This is from a book "Confess" by Colleen Hoover. "To walk something" meaning "to carry" or "to bring" - is this just a case of a missed word ("with") or an unusual phrasal verb?

**I walk into the bathroom and look at her clothes, and I want to walk them back downstairs to her**

Comment: It can also mean to accompany a person. "I walked him to the office."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This broadened transitive usage/s 'to walk carrying / carry walking', as opposed to 'to walk wheeling something, or to move something relatively heavy in lurches or at least partial gyrations as you walk':

> **walk** [transitive] *walk something*: to move a large or heavy object along the ground while walking with it
>
> - He walked the bookcase to the other end of the room.
> - We walked our bikes up the hill.

[[OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/walk_1#:%7E:text=1%5Bintransitive%2C%20transitive%5D%20to,is%20just%20learning%20to%20walk.&text=He%20walked%20slowly%20away%20from%20her.)]

> **walk** [US]{but common in the UK also; EA} 17:  to move (a bulky or heavy object) by rocking along from one side or corner to another in a
> manner suggestive of walking

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/walk)]

is becoming more common. Here is an example from [Die Trying (Jack Reacher) (#2)_Lee Child](https://novel24.com/die-trying-jack-reacher-2-s2035-c10.html)

> "I didn't ask you where she came from," Milosevic said. "Where did she
> head when she left?"
>
> The woman paused.
>
> "I didn't see," she said. "I took her garments through to the back. I
> heard the door open, but I couldn't see where she went. I was in
> back."
>
> "You just grabbed her stuff?" Milosevic said. "Rushed through to the
> back before she was out of here?"
>
> The woman faltered, like she was being accused of an impoliteness.
>
> "Not rushed," she said. "Miss Johnson was walking slow. Bad leg,
> right? I felt I shouldn't stare at her. I felt she was embarrassed. I
> walked her clothes through to the back so she wouldn't feel I was
> watching her."

But it doesn't seem to have made it into the dictionary yet.

Comment: Walking a bike is not the same as walking a bookcase. With the latter, you move it by pivoting it on different corners so that the bookcase appears to walk.

Comment: Yes. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/walk) gets as far as  '4: to move (an object) in a manner suggestive of walking'.

Comment: @AndrewLeach And neither of them is the same as walking some clothes, which you could easily carry while walking normally (since they are neither bulky nor heavy).

Comment: I'd say the usage in a non-heavy context is quite common. "She handed me the printout and I walked it over to the copier," for instance, would raise no eyebrows.

Comment: ... It might raise the odd one (or a patriotic hackle) in the UK, Alex.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, walking something could also mean “walking with” for example ‘I walked my dog’
That means bring it out for a walk.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "haul"...

I walk into the bathroom and look at her clothes, and I want to haul them back downstairs to her.